# Python : How do I add all the output?

Tags: python, file, numbers, average, addition

```
# Named constants
JAN_DAYS = 31
FEB_DAYS = 28
MARCH_DAYS = 31
APRIL_DAYS = 30
MAY_DAYS = 31
JUNE_DAYS = 30
JULY_DAYS = 31
AUG_DAYS = 31
SEPT_DAYS = 30
OCT_DAYS = 31
NOV_DAYS = 30
DEC_DAYS = 31


def main():
  # Open the file.
  steps_file = open('steps.txt', 'r')

  # Display the average steps for each month.
  average_steps(steps_file, 'January', JAN_DAYS)
  average_steps(steps_file, 'February', FEB_DAYS)
  average_steps(steps_file, 'March', MARCH_DAYS)
  average_steps(steps_file, 'April', APRIL_DAYS)
  average_steps(steps_file, 'May', MAY_DAYS)
  average_steps(steps_file, 'June', JUNE_DAYS)
  average_steps(steps_file, 'July', JULY_DAYS)
  average_steps(steps_file, 'August', AUG_DAYS)
  average_steps(steps_file, 'September', SEPT_DAYS)
  average_steps(steps_file, 'October', OCT_DAYS)
  average_steps(steps_file, 'November', NOV_DAYS)
  average_steps(steps_file, 'December', DEC_DAYS)
  

  
  # Close the file.
  steps_file.close


def average_steps(steps_file, month_name, days):
  sum = 0
  for count in range(days):
    sum += int(steps_file.readline())
  average = sum/days
  print('The average steps taken in', month_name, 'was',
    format(average, ',.1f'))


main()
```

output:
The average steps taken in January was 5,246.1

The average steps taken in February was 4,851.9

The average steps taken in March was 5,777.6

The average steps taken in April was 5,802.1

The average steps taken in May was 4,711.5

The average steps taken in June was 4,792.3

The average steps taken in July was 5,638.2

The average steps taken in August was 5,759.6

The average steps taken in September was 6,114.6

The average steps taken in October was 5,411.0

The average steps taken in November was 4,268.8

The average steps taken in December was 5,138.1

I am trying to find the average of the year

Comment: Then you just `return` the total steps(`sum`) in `average_steps`, add it to a total in `main`, and divide the total by the number of days in a year.

Comment: Side comment: `steps_file.close` You forgot the parentheses `()` on the end of the function, so you aren't actually calling it.

Comment: I don't know if this is more efficient, but I added another constant Year = 365, then I just added average_steps(steps_file, 'a Year', Year). after that I went to steps.txt and copied the steps so the line is 730 not 365.